# Selecting options based on substring in multiselectbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, multi-select

Say I have the following select box:

```
<select id = "cars">
   <option>BMW 320d</option>
   <option>BMW 330d</option>
   <option>BMW 525d</option>
   <option>Mercedes E220</option>
   <option>Peugeot 207</option>
   <option>Peugeot 307</option>
</select>
<input type = "button" id = "selectbmw" value = "Select all BMWs" />
```

I want a button that selects all cars by BMW; that is, that selects all elements that contain "BMW".

```
<select id = "cars">
   <option selected>BMW 320d</option>
   <option selected>BMW 330d</option>
   <option selected>BMW 525d</option>
   <option>Mercedes E220</option>
   <option>Peugeot 207</option>
   <option>Peugeot 307</option>
</select>
```

I thought of doing it as follows:

```
<script>
   $('#selectbmw').click(function() {
    $('#cars').multiSelect('select', 'contains:"BMW"');
    });
</script>
```

I am using [multiselect.js](http://loudev.com/) for this multiselect box. Note that my value field *does not* contain the name of the car, but an id from the database, so looking up based on value is not an option. I can set an id, name or  label attribute to the name of the car if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of selected values to multiselect, so first create an array of all options which contains `BMW` using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
$('#selectbmw').click(function () {
    var vals = $('#cars option:contains("BMW")').map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    $('#cars').multiSelect('select', vals);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QbPz7/)